# What grammar construction is "have/has to be participle"?

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice, periphrastic-modals

Recently I have heard following sentence:

> "What other basic commands do you think she **has to be told**?

I *do* understand what does this sentence mean, but I *do not* fully understand what construction is it grammar-wise?

My guessing that it is **"-have to + passive voice-"** combination here, where "-have to-" is that "*kind-of-modal-verb-but-overly-not*", am I right here?

Also, if for some reason I would like to cut off modality from sentence, can I rephrase this sentence in following way (*just for note, I want to point that someone already told her some instructions and now I am wondering what they exactly were*):

> "What other basic commands do you think she **was told**?

Comment: *What other things has she been told?*  (non-modal version) *What other things do you think she has been told?*  You are correct about the passive, and in your understanding of "has" + marked infinitive as a periphrasis for "must" + bare infinitive.

Comment: It is a passive present perfect infinitival construction, more specifically a 'catenative' construction (catenative here means chain of verbs). "Have and "be" are both catenative verbs so "to be told" is complement of "has" and "told" is complement of "be". "Have" is not modal, though the meaning is one of obligation.

Comment: @BillJ wow, thank you very much for pointing that term (*catenative*) out, never heard that term before. Actually, it makes things a little bit confusing. Just to make things clear, do I understand right that catenatives can "stack" to each other; so in may case it looks like: **Verb** + **Catenative Verb** [ _Verb_ + _Catenative Verb_ ], so two catenatives come together? Is **I need to drink** is catenative verb example too? Thank you!

Comment: Catenative complements are always non-finite clauses, sometimes immediately adjacent as in _I promised [to read the report_], and sometimes with an intervening noun as in _I persuaded **Ed** [to read the report_]. In those examples, "promise" and "persuade" are catenative verb and the catenative complements are bracketed. In your example, "need" is a catenative verb and "to drink" is a catenative complement: _I need [to drink_]. See here:[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To have to X* means to be required or forced to do X.  It's often equivalent to *must X*.

> I have to go now = I am required to go now, I must go now.

One meaning of *to have to be X* is to be required or forced to have X completed or done.

> I have to be finished by 2:00pm.
>
> I have to be gone before John gets here.

Another meaning of *to have to be X* is to be required or forced that someone else does X to you.  If there is no *by* phrase saying who, the default is *by someone* or *by anyone*.

> She will have to be told to leave, otherwise she isn't leaving.
>
> I have to be washed by the nurse since my arms are immobile.

---

> My guessing that it is "-have to + passive voice-" combination here, where "-have to-" is that "kind-of-modal-verb-but-overly-not", am I right here?

*Have* isn't a modal.  It *can be* a helping or auxillary verb as traditional grammar describes.  Like *do* or *be*.  I'm sure CEGL calls it something different.  It's definitely not a modal because it's an option to use with modals.  E.g. *I could have gone* and *I could go* are valid.

Your modals are: can, could, shall, should, will, would, may, might, must, ought and a few other not-so-common ones like dare.

But *have* in addition to being a helping/auxillary verb is also a standalone verb, and you have *have X* and a phrasal variation *have to X*.

E.g. this works:

> I would have had to have gone to the park yesterday but my friend had gone instead.

---

> can I rephrase this sentence in following way

Yep, because you are asking about the *what* the commands are, not really anything else about the commands such as whether or not she had to do them.